# How to calculate the token for a ByteOrderedPartitioner

Tags: cassandra, database-partitioning

I'm testing the behaviour of a Cassandra cluster with different configurations. One of them uses a ByteOrderedPartitioner to distribute the keys along the nodes.

The data model is made by fat rows, each of them with a integer (IntegerType) as key with a value from 0 to 9999.
I setted a ring of 10 nodes in such way:

```
Address      Rack    Status    State            Owns    Token
                                                     Token(bytes[0900])
node1         Up     Normal  5.14 MB         10.00%  Token(bytes[00])
node2         Up     Normal  377.42 MB       10.00%  Token(bytes[0100])
node3         Up     Normal  373.06 MB       10.00%  Token(bytes[0200])
node4         Up     Normal  966.15 KB       10.00%  Token(bytes[0300])
node5         Up     Normal  953.4 KB        10.00%  Token(bytes[0400])
node6         Up     Normal  953.26 KB       10.00%  Token(bytes[0500])
node7         Up     Normal  944.54 KB       10.00%  Token(bytes[0600])
node8         Up     Normal  953.4 KB        10.00%  Token(bytes[0700])
node9         Up     Normal  962.42 KB       10.00%  Token(bytes[0800])
node10        Up     Normal  961.31 KB       10.00%  Token(bytes[0900])
```

but all the load goes on the node2 and on the node3 for replica.

Why these tokens don't work? How I should fix them?

Comment: I found the problem. I setted two column families: one with a IntergerType row key (4 byte) and another with a LongType (16 byte) one.
For that reason, using tokens 4 bytes long , the first CF works but not the second one. 
Of course, with  16 bytes long tokens I have the same problem but with the second CF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should run cleanup on each node to make sure you're not seeing extra data that the node is no longer responsible for, post-bootstrap.

Once that is done, you can use the `getRangeKeySample` JMX method to get a sample of the keys on a node.  You can then adjust its token to a value that moves an appropriate amount of keys to its neighbor, if necessary.

That said: you should almost certainly be using `RandomPartitioner` instead, to avoid exactly this problem.  I've explained in posts like [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1) how you can use clustering *within* a partition key to do the kind of ordering you might otherwise be tempted to use BOP for.